# how to receive multipart/form-data requests

Tags: apex, webservices

Im trying to set up an event driven framework, which needs a public salesforce endpoint to recieve webhook posts from a 3rd party service (mailgun).

I have put together a custom rest endpoint that works fine for simple form posts using simple key-value params, but if the webhook tries to pass its post to me I get a  [{"message":"Apex REST does not support multipart/form-data requests","errorCode":"UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE"}] and I sob uncontrollably, pounding my fist on the desk.

Has anyone successfully received multipartfom data requests into salesforce? Am wondering if rather than Rest I should do this via a a sites page and somehow scrape off the incoming info. Suggestions most appreciated!

Cheers,
CH

Comment: which framework?

Comment: The mailgun service sends an event initiated post to whatever url you want. the class I have built thus far is simply an @restresource exposed via a public site.  It works for non multipart posts, but multipart doesnt work. Salesforce just fires back a 415 error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok - solved this one!

For those attempting the same - I got the bulk of the answer from this great blog post http://sfdc.arrowpointe.com/2010/02/16/endpoint-for-debugging-http-callouts/

Inspired and sensing victory, I exposed a vf page via a public site and it immediately overcame the multipart format restriction. I was unsure of what i was being sent, so using the page and controller from the afore mentioned blog post (Scott Hemmeter rocks!) I changed the debugging code to pass me the form post content via a simple custom object rather than a task (as am using a public site) and then was able to visualise clearly what was being sent to me. From there was able to proceed to extracting what i needed to handle the webhook post accordingly.

Hope this helps anyone attempting the same.

cheers,
CH

Comment: (Shameless plug!) We've got some tools for debugging API calls that might help you out without having to set up your own endpoints: http://blog.runscope.com/posts/runscope-for-salesforcecom-api-developers

Comment: The link is broken. Do you have a valid link for that blog post? Thank you